# Can a lab collection requisition be used in two different labs and still be covered by the health insurance?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance

For example, let's assume that a lab collection requisition lists two tests: test A and test B (e.g., test A and test B can be some blood tests). Can the patient do test A in one lab and test B in another lab, and still be covered by the health insurance? Or does the patient need to have two distinct lab collection requisition?

---

Answers to comments:

> Why *should* two distinct lab collection requisitions be required? – [RonJohn](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/22266/ronjohn) [3 mins ago](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/136468/can-a-lab-collection-requisition-be-used-in-two-different-labs-and-still-be-cove#comment273032_136468)

@RonJohn the insurance may not appreciate that the same req has been used twice in different places. But perhaps my concern is unfounded.

Comment: Why *should* two  distinct lab collection requisitions be required?

Comment: @RonJohn the insurance may not appreciate that the same req has been used twice in different places. But perhaps my concern is unfounded.

Comment: Please update the question.

Comment: @RonJohn done~~

Comment: You could always **ask the insurance company**.  They might say "yes" if the total cost is lower.

Comment: @RonJohn The insurance company's customer support that I can access will have no clue regarding whether the cost will be lower.

Comment: You could *tell them* that you've shopped for prices.

Answer (score 3):

In the united states the insurance company decides which lab testing company will be used to perform the test.

My spouse works in a doctors office, in the lab. Some small quick tests can be done in the office, others have to be sent out. Each insurance company decides how test A and test B are done, in the office or out of the office. Some companies even dictate that the sample be collected at a specific drawing center which means the patient has to go someplace else to get the blood collected.

If they have to send it out-of-the-office the insurance company dictates which external lab company will perform the test. The patient doesn't pick, and the doctor doesn't know. The lab staff collect the ample, check the insurance records, package the sample, generate the order, and put it in the pickup box. The transport company picks up samples at the end of the day. The lab staff then checks periodically for updated results on the website.

Exceptions to this are if the sample is collected in an emergency at an ER or hospital. More tests will be done in the on site hospital lab.

So If doctor X says get test A and test B done. Where the blood goes is out of the patients control. If the office messed up and Test B was done by an out-of-network lab, then complain. Of course if Doctor X is out of network, it is possible that your tests are also done by an out-of-network lab, and that can be very expensive.

Why is out-of-network always way more expensive? I had recent lab work done:

- $305 the Rate they would charge without insurance
- $15 the negotiated rate between the lab company and the insurance company
- $0 what I was charged in-network, because I had met my in-network deductible.

If I had gone out-of-network, I would have had to pay the lab company $305, and only $15 would have counted towards my higher out-of-network deductible.

> Can the patient do test A in one lab and test B in another lab, and
> still be covered by the health insurance? Or does the patient need to
> have two distinct lab collection requisition?

If both are blood tests the person will fill multiple tubes at the same time. If one is blood and one isn't they will collect both samples at the same time. If you want test B done by a specific lab company you would have to find a standalone drawing center for that lab, insist they send it to lab B, and you pay the bill. The insurance company could decide to reject your claim because it wasn't medically necessary because they couldn't match it to a doctors order. If they did accept it, it would be out-of-network.

Comment: Thank you, if the patient was given a lab collection requisition on paper by their physician, can't they decide to go to eg quest diagnostics or LabCorp, assuming that both are in network?

Comment: I have never had an insurance company that split basic tests across two labs in the same local area.  Does yours?

Comment: Just to clarify: the insurance company is not the one whoo split basic tests, but instead it is the patient who chooses to so. I.e., the question is: can the patient do test A in one lab (e.g., physically going to quest diagnostics to do blood test A) and test B (e.g., physically going to Lab Corp to do blood test B) in another lab, and still be covered by the health insurance?

Comment: Only if they allow this. Does yours allow this? In all my experience the 2nd lab is always out of network.

Comment: they = my health insurance provider? (let's assume that both quest diagnostics and  Lab Corp are in-network for with my health insurance plan)